# Practical witness encryption?

Tags: encryption

Assume that there is a cyphertext that I want to make such that only someone who can prove ownership of a certain public key, or set of public keys would be able to decrypt.

It is my understanding that theoretically, this is solved by witness encryption.

Is there currently *any* implementation of such an algorithm in the wild? If yes, is there anything actually practical?

**Edit:**

I realized that my question is not very clear. My goal is not only to let only someone with a particular private key decipher the encrypted data, which is just trivial encryption. Rather, I want to make it so that only someone who can prove that they have a solution to a problem (in this case, the problem would be, proving that a particular public key owns some object) can decrypt it.

Example: I want to create an open source game public key based game where secrets are spread throughout the world. The secrets are encrypted files. Only players who own a certain item (a key to a treasure for example) may decipher them. So they would need to solve the problem of "proving that I own the key", which would be done by signing a message with their private key showing that they have the required item.

I hope this makes the question clearer.

Comment: It is generally expected to prove knowledge of some private key. It is also challenging to link proof of knowledge to decryption. Any reference to such a "witness encryption", like a textbook or a paper?

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych Sure, here is a paper on the topic: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/258.pdf as well as a lecture: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sanjamg/classes/cs276-fall14/scribe/lec18.pdf 
It looks like this is incredibly powerful and exactly what I need, but I can't find any information on the state of the art research.

Comment: Probably not an answer yet, trading secret Sudoku solution looks somewhat similar to me, presented at Bitcoin workshop Financial Crypto 2016 by Bowe and Maxwell. My take on such a snark circuit: https://github.com/vadym-f/Sudoku_solvability_proof/tree/master/IEEE_ATIT_2019